# if expression inside of if expression

Tags: jsp, struts2

Is there anything wrong with code below? I aways get false in the first if expression regardless whether either variable is empty.

```
<s:if test="%{!empty #property.propertyTypeZhcn || !empty #property.propertyAge}">
    <div id="mini_hosedetail_text">
        <s:if test="%{!empty #property.propertyTypeZhcn}">
            <p>propertyType：<s:property value="fullPropertyDetail.propertyTypeZhcn"/></p>
        </s:if>

        <s:if test="%{!empty #property.propertyAge }">
            <p>PropertyAge：<s:property value="fullPropertyDetail.propertyAge"/></p>
        </s:if>
    </div>
</s:if>
```

Comment: Not very sure here, but is the syntax right?

Comment: Which taglib does the 's' prefix belong to? Maybe you can post a little more code. I also see only one if expression.

Comment: sorry, I didn't realise it was displayed incorrectly

Comment: This is the definition for 's' <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

Comment: Why you don't use the standard JSTL code library.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate on that? I thought I am using the standard struts 2 library.

Comment: @Shawn How did you define `property` bean and if it has other properties referenced in EL. Does they have getters and return values, if so what type they are. Could you post related code?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I found out where I went wrong:

1. There should be no # before the variable
2. "Empty" is a jsp tag which isn't working in struts 2 expression(at least not for me).

So the code should be, that worked for me.

```
<s:if test="%{property.propertyTypeZhcn!= null || property.propertyAge != null}">
    <div id="mini_hosedetail_text">
        <s:if test="%{property.propertyTypeZhcn != null}">
            <p>propertyType：<s:property value="fullPropertyDetail.propertyTypeZhcn"/>   </p>
        </s:if>

        <s:if test="%{property.propertyAge != null}">
            <p>PropertyAge：<s:property value="fullPropertyDetail.propertyAge"/></p>
        </s:if>
    </div>
</s:if>
```